# Can't display element

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I've bought wordpress theme a year ago and ofcourse my support ended so now I'm alone in this, so I was hoping someone can help me.

The problem appears on this page https://vivaldi-kafa.rs/pocetna-test/ where if you stick around to watch the slider, blog element at th end of the page won't load ... If you scroll immediately after the page loads the blog element loads.

If we say the scenario is the one where blog doesn't load, meaning after the page loads you stick around to watch the slider (10s), blog element won't become visible unless the user clicks somewhere on the page. I believe that is very unprofessional and I'm bad with javascript so I hope someone will help.

I tried adding `opacity: 1 !important and visible :true !important` but it's not working...

Also tried something like this but this element is never in the viewport to even force a click then ...

```
function isInViewport(el) {
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)

    );
}


const blog = document.querySelector('#blogrowpadding');

document.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
     if (isInViewport(blog)){
       document.getElementById('blogrowpadding').click();
     } else return;
}
```

Also can't even inspect the element to see what is not visible and has opacity 0, I tried making all divs in that section visible and opacity 0 but not working...So yea when I use inspect, element appears which is really frustrating.

This is not a common bug and it probably wont help anyone in the future but still it would mean a lot to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing display to initial !important